# Can the PayPal JavaScript SDK show a "Pay with Venmo" button?

Tags: paypal, venmo

My ecommerce site uses the PayPal JavaScript SDK to accept payments. The [Payment Methods](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/payment-methods/?mark=venmo#header) section of the SDK documentation lists Venmo as a payment method. But the `paypal.Buttons.render` method only makes a PayPal button. When I click the button, I don't see an option to pay with Venmo. How do I configure the PayPal JavaScript SDK to process a Venmo payment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2023 update:

For desktop web venmo can show as an option if `&enable-funding=venmo` is on the SDK line, the currency is USD, and the payer has a US IP.  On mobile browsers it can show for Safari on iOS and Chrome on Android, specifically, assuming the Venmo app is installed.

In sandbox mode `&buyer-country=US` can be added to simulate testing with a US IP. Do not add this parameter in live mode, the buttons will not render.

---

2020 answer:
Assuming you are rendering multiple buttons (the default layout:vertical, or layout:horizontal for two), a blue Venmo button will show to eligible mobile users with a US IP address who have Venmo installed on their device.

This might change in the future so any mobile user with a US IP sees Venmo. In any case, no configuration is necessary by you. All you need to do is render multiple buttons (the default) and not disable Venmo as a funding method (also default)

Comment: Any paypal/venmo documentation showing what conditions must be met for the venmo button to appear?

Comment: added some updates